# Using Hazelcast clusters in two discrete subnets, how do I bridge the two different clusters?

Tags: messaging, hazelcast, multicast, unicast

I am using Hazelcast to form two clusters in two discrete subnets. Clusters are being formed using multicast, no issues there. Some of the nodes produce over a topic and some nodes consume the same.
 Now, as I understand, I cannot use both  multicast and unicast configurations in the same node. So, how can bridge a topic across the subnet, so that messages published over one subnet can be consumed in the other?

I do not want to run all my nodes in TCP/IP configuration. I would like to use multicast for node discovery where it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure Multicast as discovery mechanism in Hazelcast, it is only used when discovering cluster members/clients. After the discovery, a TCP/IP connection is setup and this connection is used for all other communication between members or member-client. So, you do not need to worry about subnets after the cluster is formed, either with Multicast or TCP/IP discovery.

Comment: aahh..I guess, I should have read the documents more carefully. I was expecting Hazelcast to do messaging over multicast, somewhat like 29West/Ultra Messaging by Informatica, but its just the service discovery. Thanks for the clarification.